# How to set build properties from a file in Maven POM?

Tags: java, maven, ant

I need to read and filter a properties file from a location outside my project, say ${user.home}/my.properties.   This properties file looks like this:

```
res.dir=/my/stuff/here
resource.dir=C:/${res.dir}
bin.dir=${resource.dir}/bin
cfg.dir=${resource.dir}/config
```

I have to do this in both my build and in my application when it runs. This is easy to do in Ant, using the [PROPERTY tag](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html).  However, there doesn't seem to be a good way to do it in Maven.

So far I have tried the Maven `<property>` tag, the Maven `<filter>` tag and various permutations of other tags.  Either my build fails or the unit tests fail, or both.

If I hardcode these properties into the POM, everything works, so I know the problem is just reading the properties.

I looked at the [properties-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/) but the plugin no longer seems to be maintained.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I saw your comment about the plugin, so deleting my answer. Just want to let you know that whether maintained or unmaintained, it works. (or at least, used to work).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yes, I would think that if the plugin is no longer maintained or even being developed (it's listed as "Alpha") then either it's so awesome no further development was possible (doubtful), or there's a better way to do this.   I'm hoping someone will point me toward the "better way."

Comment: What brings you to the assumption that the plugin will not be maintained anymore ? Furthermore properties outside the Maven project will make your project depend on those things which will break the Maven concept to have all needed things for a Maven project inside the project itself. The question is why you are needing this?

Comment: "The question is why you are needing this?"   It's the corporate standard.  It evolved in the days of Ant.  I am no more happy with it than the rest of the Maven community seems to be.   As for the plugin, even Codehaus lists it as "pre-release."

Comment: I'm pretty much in the same boat as you are and looking for a good solution.  What did you use finally?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could simply implement your own `maven-plugin` that will take care of this for you.

Here is an example with the following structure:

```
.
 |-- pom.xml
 |-- plugin
 |   `-- pom.xml
 |   `-- src
 |       `-- main
 |           `-- java
 `-- app
     `-- pom.xml
     `-- src
         `-- main
             `-- java
```

You will need to create a Mojo that takes the properties file as an input and then propagates the properties to the `pom.xml` of the `app`. The `pom.xml` will actually not be updated but just the project data in it.

`pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>Q12082277</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <modules>
        <module>plugin</module>
        <module>app</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

`plugin/pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>Q12082277</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>Q12082277-plugin</artifactId>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

`plugin/src/main/java/com/stackoverflow/Q12082277/plugin/PropertiesMojo.java`

```
package com.stackoverflow.Q12082277.plugin;

import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.logging.Log;
import org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * @author maba, 2012-08-24
 *
 * @goal extract
 */
public class PropertiesMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    private Log log;

    /**
     * The current project representation.
     * @parameter expression="${project}"
     * @required
     * @readonly
     */
    private MavenProject project;

    /**
     * A properties file
     *
     * @parameter expression="${propertiesFile}"
     * @required
     */
    private File propertiesFile;

    @Override
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        log.info("Executing PropertiesMojo on " + propertiesFile.getAbsolutePath());

        try {
            Properties fileProperties = new Properties();
            fileProperties.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesFile));
            Properties projectProperties = project.getProperties();
            for (Object key : fileProperties.keySet()) {
                projectProperties.setProperty((String)key, (String) fileProperties.get(key));
            }
            project.getProperties().list(System.out);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new MojoFailureException("The file " + propertiesFile.getAbsolutePath() + " was not found!", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void setLog(Log log) {
        this.log = log;
    }
}
```

You will use this plugin from the following `app/pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>Q12082277</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>Q12082277-app</artifactId>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>Q12082277-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>extract</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <propertiesFile>${user.home}/my.properties</propertiesFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.stackoverflow.Q12082277.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

And then you will have to add the following `app.properties` that will work as a template and take the values that we have just read from file and set them and create a concrete file `app.properties` that will be reachable from within the jar.

`app/src/main/resources/app.properties`

```
res.dir=${res.dir}
resource.dir=${resource.dir}
bin.dir=${bin.dir}
cfg.dir=${cfg.dir}
```

And finally here is a test application that just loads the `app.properties` from the classpath and prints the result.

`app/src/main/java/com/stackoverflow/Q12082277/App.java`

```
package com.stackoverflow.Q12082277;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * @author maba, 2012-08-23
 */
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ClassLoader loader = App.class.getClassLoader();
        InputStream in = loader.getResourceAsStream("app.properties");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(in);
        properties.list(System.out);
    }
}
```

Now you can stand in the top directory and execute

```
mvn install
```

Then go down into the `app` folder and execute

```
mvn exec:java
```

And it will print

```
-- listing properties --
resource.dir=C://my/stuff/here
cfg.dir=C://my/stuff/here/config
bin.dir=C://my/stuff/here/bin
res.dir=/my/stuff/here
```

Which is exactly what you wanted.

Comment: This appears to be the best answer - I'm not happy that this gaping hole in Maven's toolset hasn't been addressed, but hey, welcome to open source, I guess.   :-(

Answer (score 5):

I think it would be better if you turned the properties file into a *template* file and take the properties from the `pom.xml` using [maven resource filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).

A simple setup might look like this

`pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>Q12082277</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <properties>
        <res.dir>/default/stuff/here</res.dir>
        <resource.dir>${res.dir}</resource.dir>
        <bin.dir>${resource.dir}/bin</bin.dir>
        <cfg.dir>${resource.dir}/config</cfg.dir>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <!-- Your dependencies -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>
```

`src/main/resources/app.properties`

```
res.dir=${res.dir}
resource.dir=${resource.dir}
bin.dir=${bin.dir}
cfg.dir=${cfg.dir}
```

`src/main/java/com/stackoverflow/Q12082277/App.java`

```
package com.stackoverflow.Q12082277;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * @author maba, 2012-08-23
 */
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ClassLoader loader = App.class.getClassLoader();
        InputStream in = loader.getResourceAsStream("app.properties");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(in);
        properties.list(System.out);
    }
}
```

`System.out`

```
-- listing properties --
resource.dir=/default/stuff/here
cfg.dir=/default/stuff/here/config
bin.dir=/default/stuff/here/bin
res.dir=/default/stuff/here
```

The `pom.xml` will have the default properties that are used by everybody.

If you want to override the values then call maven with input parameters:

```
mvn install -Dres.dir=/my/stuff/here -Dresource.dir="C:/${res.dir}"
```

`System.out`

```
-- listing properties --
resource.dir=C://my/stuff/here
cfg.dir=C://my/stuff/here/config
bin.dir=C://my/stuff/here/bin
res.dir=/my/stuff/here
```

By doing it this way everybody will have the same view of the properties and you can override them if you want to when running on your own machine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately the way it is currently laid out (with the properties in a separate file) is a corporate standard and is not up for discussion, so I'm stuck using it the way it is.

Comment: @user1071914 Try to use the maven antrun plugin. It might do what you need.

Comment: @user1071914 I added another answer that implements a simple mojo that does what you want.