# Specify pom properties via a properties file?

Tags: java, maven, properties

Due to the way my build system is designed (RTC Build Engine), I would like to provide maven with property values via a properties file, instead of specifying -Dkey=value for every property.

I found a couple of questions on S.O. ([How to set build properties from a file in Maven POM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12082277/827480) and [How to read an external properties file in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/q/849389/827480)) that relate precisely to this question, but they are relatively old, and both require custom plugins to work (in alpha state).

I realize that passing parameters to Maven like this is probably not the best solution, but the other option is specifying everything on the command line via -D settings which is not ideal either.

Furthermore, given that this properties file is only really used by the build engine (and not by the individual developer), I don't truly believe it belongs in the pom.  But I cannot find any other mechanism that would allow me to specify a plugin to use - settings.xml does not permit specifying plugins.

Is my only choice in this case to use a plugin and specify it in the project pom?

Comment: Can you give real examples of what kind of properties you would like to provide?

Comment: @khmarbaise : ex: -Dcore-version=1234 -Dlib-version=1234 -Dbuild-version=9999, -Dbuild-date=20150101, etc.

Comment: Why do you like to define lib-version? Does not make sense? Cause they are defined in the pom. What i can understand is using things like build-version...Build-Date (this could be handled in different ways).

Comment: @khmarbaise I don't like to define these values parameter style, but unfortunately, I have no choice.  I am migrating an existing production build system from one source control/build system to a different one, and their current build uses scripts and manually defined vars.  It is an iterative process, and the long term goal is to remove these vars altogether, but as a first step, it has to be done this way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in the pom you can place...

```
<properties>
    <core-version>1234</core-version>
    <lib-version>1234</lib-version>
    <build-version>9999</lib-version>
    <build-date>20150101</build-date>
</properties>
```

with all the properties you require.

Or you can use...

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <files>
                <file>dev.properties</file>
              </files>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

and the file `dev.properties` will contain the properties

```
core-version=1234
lib-version=1234
build-version=9999
build-date=20150101
...
```

Or... you can inject the properties using a settings.xml file as shown [here](http://maven.apache.org/examples/injecting-properties-via-settings.html)

You may also find the Maven build number plugin useful... [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: I had found that plugin already, but have concerns about the fact that it hasn't been touched since 2009.  So I was looking to see if there was a "better" way of doing this.  I am surprised that in 5 years, no one has come up with a different, more accepted way than using a plugin that is still in "alpha" state.

Comment: What about deliviering patches for the plugin and improve it? It's open source...?

Comment: I basically ended up with this solution.  Not my preferred one, but functional for the time being.  Thanks.

Comment: Ack.  Just discovered that I cannot specify version numbers using properties set via a plugin as maven does not view the pom as being valid if there are undefined version #s.  Hence it does not even kick off its lifecycle.  I even tried putting the plugin in the validate phase, but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

The best in such cases is to upgrade to at least Maven 3.2.1 which supports defining such properties on the command line like the following:

```
mvn -Drevision=1234 -Dchangelist=WhatEver -Dsha1=XXXX clean package
```

But you can only use the above names.

[Excerpt from release notes:](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/release-notes.html)

> A simple change to prevent Maven from emitting warnings about versions
>   with property expressions. Allowed property expressions in versions
>   include ${revision}, ${changelist}, and ${sha1}. These properties can
>   be set externally, but eventually a mechanism will be created in Maven
>   where these properties can be injected in a standard way. For example
>   you may want to glean the current Git revision and inject that value
>   into ${sha1}. This is by no means a complete solution for continuous
>   delivery but is a step in the right direction.