# Can Maven have local, project properties?

Tags: maven, properties-file

We have a Maven project where each developer needs to use their local project settings. Since they should not be stored in the Git repository, we can't speficy them in the pom.xml file.

We have considered to use the ~/.m2/settings.xml file but since this file store properties *user-wide* and not *per project*, they interfere with each other. For example:

```
<profiles>

  <profile>
    <id>project1</id>
    <properties>
      <sftp-endpoint>10.201.50.14</sftp-endpoint>
      <sftp-password>secretpass</sftp-password>
    </properties>
  </profile>

  <profile>
    <id>project2</id>
    <properties>
      <sftp-endpoint>12.34.56.78</sftp-endpoint>
      <sftp-password>pencil</sftp-password>
    </properties>
  </profile>

</profiles>

<activeProfiles>
  <activeProfile>project1</activeProfile>
  <activeProfile>project2</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

If I try to use this file, when I work on project1 I also get local properties from project2. They must have the same names since a lot depend on them.

Is there any way I can have local properties per project in Maven?

Comment: How about having 2 poms? The good one for the git and the custom one only local?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify pom properties via a properties file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987065/specify-pom-properties-via-a-properties-file)

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly This looks promising. Will try it out.

Comment: Why do you need an sftp access in your Maven project?

Answer (score 2):

@AnthonyAccioly comment gave the big clue.

I wanted to post my solution (that differs from the proposed duplicate question) since it may be of use to someone else. I ended up writing a small Mojo plugin to deal with this.

In the **pom.xml** (stored in Git) includes the common properties. It looks like:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.mycompany.mytool</groupId>
      <artifactId>a1-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>

      <configuration>
        <localproperties>dev.properties</localproperties>
        <common.prop1>value1</common.prop1>
        <common.prop2>value2</common.prop2>
      </configuration>
      ...
    <plugin>
  <plugins>
<build>
```

The **dev.properties** file (not stored in Git) looks like:

```
local.prop3=value3
local.prop4=value4
```

This way, my plugin retrieves the common properties from the pom.xml that is stored in Git, while the local properties (that differ per developer) are stored in the file `dev.properties`. A simple Java method reads the properties file using the java.util.Properties class. Easy.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Environment variables** 
    You can use environment script per environment which defines environment variables like `sftp-endpoint` and `sftp-password`. These files are then added to `.gitignore` and distributed manually to the dev team. Then you can use these properties in your pom like `${env.VARIABLE_NAME}` or `${env}.VARIABLE_NAME`
2. **Password Encryption** 
   Use Maven built-in [password encryption](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html)