# Dependency not resolved from BOM file

Tags: java, maven

Trying to reslove dependency using BOM file but below configuration is not working.

=== BOM File configuration ===

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>bom-dependency</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>bom-dependency</name>
    <description>BOM dependency</description>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
                <version>12.2.0.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

=== POM file configuration ===

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Test</name>
    <description>Demo Project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>demo</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom-dependency</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        

</project>
```

Can someone please let me why its not taking dependency from BOM file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this part from the definition in your BOM:

```xml
<type>pom</type>
<scope>import</scope>
```

Also remove the `<version>` tag completely from the dependency in your test project.

Comment: while build project then getting this issue after removing the version tag  'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.oracle:ojdbc8:jar is missing

Comment: The version should be coming from your BOM, if you entered it correctly.

Comment: Now all are working fine. Thank you. One more point how can we get that parent dependency version from BOM file? For example  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent> is available in pom file. I need to get that version from BOM file. How to get that?

Comment: any other way to do that?

Comment: You can set the parent version to `${revision}` and supply the version on command line.

Comment: That is not feasible.. If we can handle this using BOM then it will be really good

Comment: Sorry, but the parent POM version cannot be supplied by a BOM.

Answer (score 0):

There is a previous definition in spring-boot-starter-parent:

```xml
<dependency>                                                              
  <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>                                     
  <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>                                         
  <version>${ojdbc.version}</version>                                     
</dependency>
```

You can override Spring Boot's version by setting the property:

```xml
<oracle-database.version>12.2.0.1</oracle-database.version>
```

But that will override all Oracle artifacts.  If you're going to keep Spring Boot parent, all you can do is create an explicit dependency.